# Filling an array with numbers sequentially

Tags: php, arrays, increment

I have a number (e.g. 6) that is dynamically generated and I would like to fill an array with the numbers 1 through the dynamically generated number (in this example, 6):

```
array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

The only way I know to do this at the moment is by using a for loop, but I'm wondering if there's a better way, something similar to `array_fill`. I looked at array_fill, but it doesn't look like it will take a number and increment it for a set number of times.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php):

```
$arr = range(1,6);
// Returns an array of elements from start to limit, inclusive.
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks! (I'll accept the answer in 6 minutes - didn't realize they have a minimum amount of time I have to wait from asking the question to marking it as answered).

Comment: @Francis No problem! Just happy to help.

Comment: If you want the keys to be the same as the values, you should combine this with array_combine:

Comment: $num_range = range(1, 50);
$resultNums = array_combine($num_range, $num_range);

Answer (score 5):

This is what you are looking for:

```
range(1, 6)
```